# Summing elems of array using binary recursion

Tags: recursion, binary, trace

I wasn't starting to understand linear recursion and then I thought I practice up on sorting algorithms and then quick sort was where I had trouble with recursion. So I decided to work with a simpler eg, a binary sum that I found online. I understand that recursion, like all function calls, are executed one @ a time and not at the same time (which is what multi-threading does but is not of my concern when tracing). So I need to execute all of recursive call A BEFORE recursive call B, but I get lost in the mix. Does anyone mind tracing it completely. The e.g. I have used of size, n = 9 where elems are all 1's to keep it simple.

```
/**
 * Sums an integer array using binary recursion.
 * @param arr, an integer array
 * @param i starting index
 * @param n size of the array
 * floor(x) is largest integer <= x
 * ceil(x) is smallest integer >= x
 */
public int binarySum(int arr[], int i, int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return arr[i];
    return binarySum(arr, i, ceil(n/2)) + binarySum(arr,i + ceil(n/2), floor(n/2));
}
```

Comment: I tried to trace like on this site with Fibonacci e.g. but it becomes a nightmare for me. please see: http://cis.stvincent.edu/html/tutorials/swd/recur/recur.html. I'd appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 2):

What I personally do is start with an array of size 2. There are two elements.

return binarySum(arr, i, ceil(n/2)) + binarySum(arr,i + ceil(n/2), floor(n/2)) will do nothing but split the array into 2 and add the two elements. - case 1

now, this trivial starting point will be the lowest level of the recursion for the higher cases.

now increase n = 4. the array is split into 2 : indices from 0-2 and 2-4.

now the 2 elements inside indices 0 to 2 are added in case 1 and so are the 2 elements added in indices 2-4.

Now these two results are added in this case.

Now we are able to make more sense of the recursion technique, some times understanding bottom up is easier as in this case!

Now to your question consider an array of 9 elements : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

n = 9 => ceil(9/2) = 5, floor(9/2) = 4

Now first call (top call) of binarySum(array, 0, 9)

now n = size is not 1

hence the recursive call....

return binarySum(array, 0, 5) + binarySum(array, 5, 4)

now the first binarySum(array, 0 ,5) operates on the first 5 elements of the array and the second binarySum(array,5,4) operates on the last 4 elements of the array

hence the array division can be seen like this: 1 2 3 4 5 | 6 7 8 9

The first function finds the sum of the elements: 1 2 3 4 5

and the second function finds the sum of the elements 6 7 8 9

and these two are added together and returned as the answer to the top call!

now how does this 1+2+3+4+5 and 6+7+8+9 work? we recurse again....

so the tracing will look like

```
                            1 2 3 4 5 | 6 7 8 9

             1 2 3 | 4 5                          6 7 | 8 9

     1 2 | 3              4 | 5            6 | 7            8 | 9
```

[1 | 2]***_*__**[3]***_*__**[4   5]***_*__**[6   7]**__*_***[8   9]

Till this we are fine..we are just calling the functions recursively.

But now, we hit the base case!

if (n == 1)
        return arr[i];

[1 +  2]***_*___**[3]**__*_*_**[4  +  5]***_*___**[6  +  7]**__*_*_**[8  +  9]

[3     +     3]   ***_*___**     [9]       **__*_*_**[13     +         17]

```
      [6          +           9]                      [30]

                  [15                +                 30] 

                                   [45]
```

which is the sum.

So for understanding see what is done to the major instance of the problem and you can be sure that the same thing is going to happen to the minor instance of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This [example](http://codebloodedvalley.blogspot.in/2014/07/recursion-binary-sum.html)  explains binary sum with trace in java

the trace is based on index of array , where  0  - is yours starting index and 8 is length of the array

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum(int* arr, int p, int k) {
    if (p == k)
        return arr[k];
    int s = (p + k) / 2;
    return sum(arr, p, s) + sum(arr, s + 1, k);
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?